# Error assigning output in always comb blocks System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I keep having this issue where I'm trying to assign the outputs values in always comb blocks, but it keeps throwing me an error every time I compile saying

```
Error-[IBLHS-NT] Illegal behavioral left hand side
hits.sv, 10
Net type cannot be used on the left side of this assignment.
The offending expression is : NumHits
Source info: NumHits = 7'b0;
```

I'm not sure why this is happening I'm pretty sure it should be legal to assign output values in always comb blocks, could anyone help me out?

```
`default_nettype none

module checkHits
    (output logic hit, [6:0] NumHits, [4:0] BiggestShipHit,
    input logic bomb, [3:0] x, [3:0] y);

    always_comb begin
       hit = 1'b0;
       NumHits = 7'b0000000;
       BiggestShipHit = 5'b00000;
       if (bomb == 1'b1) begin
           if ((x == 4'b0001 && y == 4'b1010)) begin
              hit = 1'b1;
              NumHits = 7'b0000010;
              BiggestShipHit = 5'b00010;
              end
           else if ((x == 4'b0001 && y == 4'b0001)) begin
              hit = 1'b1;
              NumHits = 7'b0000011;
              BiggestShipHit = 5'b01000;
              end
           else if (x == 4'b1010 && y == 4'b0001) begin
              hit = 1'b1;
              NumHits = 7'b0000010;
              BiggestShipHit = 5'b00001;
              end
           else if (x == 4'b1010 && y == 4'b1010) begin
              hit = 1'b0;
              end
           else if (x == 4'b0001) begin
              if ((x == 4'b0010 && y + 1'b1 == 4'b1010) || (x == 4'b0010 &&
                   y == 4'b1010) || (x == 4'b0010 && y - 1'b1 == 4'b1010) ||
                   (x + 1'b1 == 4'b0010 && y + 1'b1 == 4'b1010) ||
                   (x + 1'b1 == 4'b0010 && y == 4'b1010) ||
                   (x + 1'b1 == 4'b0010 && y -1'b1 == 4'b1010)) begin
                       hit = 1'b1;
                       NumHits += 1;
                       if (BiggestShipHit <= 5'b00010)
                          BiggestShipHit = 5'b00010;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you omitted specifying explicit data types for `NumHits` and `BiggestShipHit` but used just ranges - they become implicit nets that cannot be procedurally assigned. See *23.2.2.3 Rules for determining port kind, data type, and direction* in the 1800-2017 LRM.

The correct way is to add the `logic` keyword.

```
module checkHits
    (output logic hit, logic [6:0] NumHits, logic [4:0] BiggestShipHit,
    input logic bomb, logic [3:0] x, y);
```

Although the rules do not require it for your inputs, I would always add explicit data types in port declarations. Makes much easier to read,

Comment: does not look like lrm is very clear about it. it says that the port kind/type has to be inherited. There are also implicit declaration rules which might contradict it at least in 2012.

Comment: I think the LRM may not be clear, but it is specific about this. For subsequent ports, if you omit everything, everything is inherited. Direction is alway in inherited. But data type/port kind are not inherited once you specify any part of it.

Comment: thanks for the help! I think declaring logic would fix the problem, but what I ended up doing was moving all the different signals of different widths to a different line.